# Different run dialogues

Tags: customization

I would like to know how does called the category of programs that runs other programs, aka `run dialog` or `ALT-F2-programs`. I do know few of them such as `gmrun`, `bashrun` and `dmenu` but I dont know how to find other programs like this. If I'm searching for `run dialogues programs` I couldn't find anything useful. 
So, can you help me with this: list some of the most popular `run dialogues` programs and give any hint how to find similar one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such programs are sometimes called "Launchers" or "Program launchers" or "Application launchers". Some more launchers are Kupfer, Albert, Ulauncher. Rofi is a launcher that initially expanded on dmenu, but that, besides being able to substitute for the latter, has a lot possibilities on its own.

You will probably have more hits and inspiration looking on the internet for "Linux application launchers", where you will find a lot of "top 5" blogs. You can then search by name in Ubuntu Software or a package manager (e.g. Synaptic) to see whether the application is available there. Some are not available in the software repositories of Ubuntu, and can only be installed in alternative (less secure) ways.